# My function is not returning a rounded number. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <script>
  function roundNumber() {
  var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
  var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
  var n = (f - n)
  document.getElementById("ng").innerHTML = n
  var rounded = n.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("n") = rounded;
  }
  </script>
```

Looking for a rounded number in the decimal place. Example: 91.46367 to 91.5

Comment: did you console out the value of `ng` before using `.toFixed(3)` ?

Comment: to be clear `toFixed(x)` and `x` is the number of digits to appear after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Math.round( num * 10) / 10 works, here is an example...

var number = 12.3456789;
var rounded = Math.round( number * 10 ) / 10; // rounded is 12.3
```

if you want it to have one decimal place, even when that would be a 0, then add...

```
var fixed = rounded.toFixed(1);
// fixed is always to 1dp
// BUT: returns string!

// to get it back to number format
parseFloat( number.toFixed(2) )
// 12.34
// but that will not retain any trailing zeros

// so, just make sure it is the last step before output,
// and use a number format during
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `toFixed` takes a number which indicates the number of digits to appear after the decimal point; this may be a value between 0 and 20, inclusive. The returned number is rounded if necessary.

See the [MDN on toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
function computeGrade() {
  var cg = document.getElementById("cg").value;
  var dg = document.getElementById("dg").value;
  var wof = document.getElementById("wof").value;
  var ng = (dg - (cg * (1 - (wof / 100)))) / (wof / 100)
  document.getElementById("ng").innerHTML = "Needed grade: " + ng + "%";
  var rounded = ng.toFixed(1); // number indicated digits to show after decimal and includes rounding
  document.getElementById("rounded").innerHTML = "Rounded grade: " + rounded + "%";
}
```

```html
<input id="cg" value="90" /><br />
<input id="dg" value="80" /><br />
<input id="wof" value="75" /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="computeGrade()" value="Compute" /><br />
<span id="ng"></span><br />
<span id="rounded"></span>
```